# Scala: Append on list to other list with reassignment: Reassignment to val error

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I know i can concat two lists a & b to result c like this in scala. But how can i do same thing if i do not want extra variable c and hold result in variable a.

```
 val a = List(1,2,3)
 val b = List(4,5,6)
 val c = a ::: b (I do not want this extra variable c and want to hold result in val a only)

Basically appending List b to List a:
Something like [ a = a ::: b]
This is giving me error: Reassignment to val.
```

Answer (score 3):

A `val` is final. Once a value has been assigned to it (`List(1,2,3)`), a new value cannot be reassigned to it.
Use a `var`

Answer (score 1):

Use `var` instead of `val`. `val` can't be re-assigned.

Answer (score 0):

You can treat it as `a:::b` anywhere in your code . BUT note that even if you define a new `val c = a:::b` it does not allocate more memory size (as the size of `a` and `b`). it uses data sharing of `a` and `b` so it good practice to create a new val if it makes your code more readable (or makes your life easier) otherwise just use a:::b . in general it is a better practice than using a 'var'